# Motion Detection in Kurento WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, kurento

we are working on Kurento Media Server . We run all example of node.js like platedetector,pointdetector , crowddetector etc

We are facing problem how to detect motion . Let suppose if anything moves in front of camera and it detects any change then calls an event .

In simple words if anything moves in front of camera then we want trigger an Event

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by default in kms-filters
https://github.com/Kurento/kms-filters/tree/master/src/gst-plugins/movementdetector